# Update made me unable to decrypt my disk?

Tags: 18.04, decryption

I installed an update via the Ubuntu updater, then I entered "reboot" in the console. 
Now when I enter my password to decrypt my disk it says that the password is wrong. When I start in Recovery Mode the same password works...

Hope someone can help :)

Comment: Not much for us to go on. Can you check from recovery mode if there are logs written when it is stated it is wrong? I doubt your update did this though because I would believe we would be swarmed with topics.

Comment: What am i looking for in the logs? I looked through them but really did catch my eye... im grep(ing) my way through looking for keywords like "update", "encr*", "error" but i cant seem to find a clue

Comment: those are it yes; mainly things like "error"  or "invalid", "incorrect". Hmm odd then. I expected invalid logins to be logged. Seems illogical not to do that.

Comment: could this be becuase it is "before" the actual OS? kinda like bios